# Does CouchDB limit the number of views per design doc?

Tags: couchdb, scale

I'd like to build an application that creates a new _view for each user of the application. I'm wondering about scale. A a million users (should we be so fortunate) does one long list of views within a design doc still function with some performance?

**Update:** *What I'm trying to accomplish*

I've got three types of docs that'll sit in my databse: docs that describe projects, docs that describe users, and docs that describe actions. Each action will belong to one and only one user, and one and only one project. I'll have views (HTML views) for users, their profile pages, and views for projects. So, I'd like to be able to grab all of a given user's actions in one request (a couchdb _view perhaps). I'd also like to be able to grab all the actions taken for a project in one request (another couchdb _view... perhaps).

**Update 2 : )**

So users will likely update their profiles, adjusting user docs, and project leaders will likely update project information, changing project docs in the db. Actions are permanent and happen once, so no conflicts there.

Comment: That doesn't seem like a good idea, since each document that gets added to the database would trigger the map function of each view.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @KimStebel updated the question with more detail : ) I realize my set up is somewhat relational, but I would like to stick with a noSQL DB if possible. I am open to messing with the architecture of the data. One challenge is avoiding CouchDB conflicts wherever possible.

Comment: I don't see how conflicts play a role in your requirements. Conflicts result from documents being updated concurrently. Since you don't talk about any updates in your question, I can't tell you how to avoid conflicts in your case. One common way to avoid conflicts is to avoid updates altogether.

Comment: Let me update the question again with some detail on updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That only requires two CouchDB views: One that indexes actions by user and one that indexes actions by project. Assuming you have an action document that looks like this:

```
{
  "type": "action",
  "project": "someProjectID",
  "user": "someUserID"
}
```

You can write a view with the following map function:

```
function(doc) {
  if (doc.type == "action") {
    emit(doc.project, null);
  }
}
```

Querying the view with `include_docs=true` and `key=someProjectId` will return all actions for a given project.